# Is there any way that a Firefox addon can be checked to see if it's trustworthy?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, malware

There are many Firefox addons that ask for login information so that they can login to another site (Twitter addons, StumbledUpon, ScribeFire etc.).

How can you tell if a Firefox addon that asks for login information is trustworthy and won't also redirect your login information somewhere else?

At the moment I'm using ScribeFire to post Blog information (a very useful addon that makes posting quicker/easier), but the only ways I can "trust" it are by looking around the Web and seeing if there have been any issues, and by the number of downloads there has been from the Mozilla site over a period of time.

Or is the fact that the addon is available for download from Mozilla enough to say that it has been checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to really be sure is to check the code.
MOst extensions can be read by simply unzipping the containers they're in.
Other than that you just need to trust the community.  Search for anyone reporting issues.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if this is the general consensus? I suspect I'm just being slightly paranoid :)

Comment: Accept this as the answer for now, unless someone comes up with anything more convincing.